# Email header for email classification

Tags: email, header

I have been playing with email headers.  I am trying to include a record identification number in the email header so that if I send an email and then it is replied to, the reply that I receive will be automatically allocated within my email client based on the record identification in the header.

When I have tried to do this, on reply to my email the original header including my record identification is deleted.

Is there are better way to do this?  I was thinking I could just add it to the subject however  I would rather the identifier be invisible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

[Address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) might be what you're looking for, if your email client supports it. You would put the tag in your reply-to address, not in an email header. I don't think you can expect your headers to remain in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Matching replies with the original message is exactly what the standard Message-ID: header is for. It's a unique string that identifies the email, and it's generally included in replies. You needn't -and shouldn't- invent any new headers nor any special processing of existing headers for this. (If you want to understand all the gory details, look at the email RFC documents.)

If they're not displaying for you, the problem is not that the information isn't there, but rather that your email-program isn't very smart. (Or maybe you have to turn on some option in the email program...)